# change XmlElement Name property

Tags: c#, xml, replace, c++-cli

I would like to change the Name property of an XmlElement in c++/cli.

I would like to do `myXmlElem.Name = "xyz"`, but the compiler tells me that I can't do a set operation on the Name property.

i.e.

```
<abc/>
```

changed to

```
<xyz/>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can't change the Name property of an XmlElement like that (Name is read only).

you can however do something like the following (example in C#).

```
XmlElement xyz = myXmlElem.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("xyz");
myXmlElem.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(xyz, myXmlElem);
```

EDIT In response to your comment

```
XmlElement xyz = myXmlElem.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("xyz");

for(int i = 0; i < myXmlElem.ChildNodes.Count; i++){
    XmlNode child = myXmlElem.ChildNodes[i];
    xyz.AppendChild(child.CloneNode(true));
}

myXmlElem.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(xyz, myXmlElem);
```

Comment: Yea, I figured that was my last resort.. but I also have a bunch of attributes and children for the original element I would have to move over too. Sounds like a headache!

Comment: myXmlElem.ChildNodes[i] will include the attributes?

Comment: yes, it'll include any type of node (Attribute, Text, Element etc...)

Comment: @Matt The ChildNodes properties _does not_ contain attributes. As can be demonstrated by running the example code on the [ChildNodes MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In the example provided the title and price are printed but the ISBN is not.

Comment: +1, You're correct, it won't contain the attributes. Sorry for the miss-information.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Linq to Xml which supports changing the name of an XElement:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<foo><bar /></foo>");
doc.Root.Name = "changed";//now it will look like <changed><bar /></changed>
```