# Dynamically change an element name in an xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file with several thousand records configured like so;

```
<RBS>
  <RBS>0</RBS>
  <ApplicantType>Seller</ApplicantType>
  <RBSType>2</RBSType>
  <RBSName>Unknown Seller</RBSName>
  <FishingAuthority>GBR</FishingAuthority>
</RBS>
```

When coveting the contents of the file to be displayed in a Dev Express data grid using the following code

```
private DataTable GetDataFromXML() {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(path);
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

All bar the RBS element get transferred.  My gut instinct is that having an inner element named the same as the outer element is the root cause of the problem.  In order to ascertain if this is the case I need to rename the RBS inner element to say RbsNumber.

However using a simple string replace function is going to catch the outer elements as well.

Is there a way to rename just the inner RBS element without renaming the outer one?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  The first RBS is the table name and the second is a column name.  It shouldn't be an issue.  Can you explain the real issue.

Comment: @jdweng My thoughts exactly.  I have since tried this with a couple of other grids and got the result that I expected to see.  Looks as if it may be an issue with the dx grid.  Thanks for taking the time to look none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Data-table parser does not understand xml element depth. You were correct. This case is a possible duplicate of, [change XmlElement Name property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320809/change-xmlelement-name-property)

You can change\ manipulate xml elements if you have the xml content loaded to XmlDocument.